# CollectionUtils.retainAll method doesn't work (Java)

Tags: java, arraylist, compare

I have two ArrayLists. I want to compare them, to get the number of common elements. Or just a list with the common elements.

When I try to do this with CollectionUtils.retainAll, it doesn't know this method I think?

It says it cannot find the symbol 'Variable CollectionUtils', so it also doesn't know the method? Or what do I wrong?

My code:

```
ArrayList<String> lijst1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inhoud1.split("AT")));
ArrayList<String> lijst2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(inhoud2.split("AT")));

ArrayList matches = CollectionUtils.retainAll(lijst1,lijst2);
```

Sorry if it's something easy. It probably will be.

Comment: How have you imported `CollectionUtils`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CollectionUtils` class is a part of the Apache Commons Collections library, and is not part of the Java API, hence unavailable by default.
Include the library as a JAR on your classpath, or use Maven to add it, then import `org.apache.commons.collections4.CollectionUtils`.

You can also use `lijst1.retainAll(lijst2)`, but you'll have to use it slightly differently, since `ArrayList#retainAll` acts by side-effects (that is, it will update `lijst1` instead of returning a new collection.